# Generate Report between two dates

Tags: android

i want to retrieve data between two dates below is my query its wrong i need it correct so anyone help me please 
also i don't need rawquery i want to did like below

```
public Cursor CstmRpot(String fd, String td) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String[] columns = new String[] {EX_RowID,EX_Cattype, EX_Date, EX_Price, EX_Type };
Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(Food_TABLE, columns, EX_Date  + "= BETWEEN '"+ fd + "' 
 AND  '" + td + "'" , null, null, null, null);
if (c != null) {

       c.moveToFirst();

      }
return c;

}
```

here is my loggat my query is just want little change i think but now i am confuse what can i do with it

```
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   
activity ComponentInfo{com.exmang/com.exmang.CstmrptShow}:  
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'19-1-2014'": syntax error: , while  
compiling: SELECT _id, Ecattype, Ecdate, Ecprice, itype FROM FoodTable WHERE
EcdateBETWEEN '19-1-2014' AND '27-1-2014'
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  
Method)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Caused by:  
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'19-1-2014'": syntax error: , while  
compiling: SELECT _id, Ecattype, Ecdate, Ecprice, itype FROM FoodTable WHERE  
EcdateBETWEEN '19-1-2014' AND '27-1-2014'
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at  
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at    
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at    
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.  
<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.   
<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at  
com.exmang.ExMgDB.CstmRpot(ExMgDB.java:112)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
com.exmang.CstmrptShow.displayListView(CstmrptShow.java:31)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
com.exmang.CstmrptShow.onCreate(CstmrptShow.java:23)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-27 00:22:24.827: E/AndroidRuntime(399):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that finally translates to SQL the right syntax is:

```
WHERE SOME_DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN <Date1> AND <Date2>
```

So your problem (or one of your problems) seems to be here.

```
EX_Date  + "= BETWEEN '"
```

Remove the `=` sign.

Comment: sir it not work i remove it but some some how chenge my loggate before

Comment: Ensure what is sent to your DB is a valid SQL query. I am assuming you're using a SQL DB.

Comment: no sir i use the sqllite for android app i added my loggat now so please check it again also i set loggat my data is go to DB correct

Comment: Add a space now before your BETWEEN. Like this: `" BETWEEN '"`